# set display resolution in X11 forwarding

Tags: x11

I have a machine running `RHEL6.7`, this machine is connected via `ssh` to another machine and I am forwarding graphics using `X11` forwarding.

The problem is that when I run the program, the scaling is all messed up on my machine. Is there a way to tell the server the display of my screen?

Answer (score 2):

Both the local and remote X11 applications are actually using the same X11 server: the one that is actually connected to the display you're physically viewing.

If the scaling of local X11 applications is OK, but remote X11 applications have messed-up scaling, then there must be some settings - possibly environment variables - that are affecting the scaling of local applications, but are not replicated to the remote session.

Assuming that the remote X11 applications use the same X11 toolkit libraries as the local ones with OK scaling, you'll just need to identify and replicate the missing settings on the remote session, and that might be the quickest way to fix the problem. (However, this might be just a workaround rather than an actual fix - see below)

If the remote X11 applications use a different toolkit, you might have to find the documentation of the remote toolkit library and find out which settings that toolkit requires for an equivalent effect.

However, you should also use `xdpyinfo | grep -e dimensions -e resolution` and verify that the reported information makes sense - not only the pixel resolution, but also the Dots-Per-Inch values and the physical display size (reported in millimeters). These parameters normally come from the display's EDID information, which might sometimes be incorrect, and will throw off all X11 scaling unless worked around at the X11 toolkit level.

If you find that the physical display size and/or the DPI values don't make sense for your actual display, you should modify your local X server configuration to override the wrong values with correct ones. After applying the override and restarting the X11 server, you might have to undo any X11 toolkit-level workarounds for incorrect scaling, as they should no longer be needed and might now result in an error in the opposite sense, as the root cause of the scaling error will now be corrected.

Comment: The days where the values reported by `xdpyinfo` were taken from the EDID and made any kind of sense are looong gone -- nowadays [96dpi is forced](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23705) completely ignoring the size of the monitor(s).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `xserver` and have the `xrandr` package installed then you use it to change the display settings:

`xrandr --size 1920x1080`

That's just an example size. You can replace it with whatever suits you. Just make sure that it doesn't exceed what your GPU and monitor support.